# Re-rendering of a template doesn't allow me to permanently change an element's class?

Tags: meteor

I have a sortable list.

```
<template name="the_playlist">
        {{#each main_list}}
          <li id="{{index}}" class="list_element">
                 <div class="next_song">...</div>   
                 <div class="destroy">...</div>
                 <div class="element_style">{{song_title}}</div>
          </li>
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

And this is the `main_list` that it prints from.

```
Template.the_playlist.main_list = function(){
    //if ret is valid, it will have a songs member
    var ret = Links.find().fetch()[0];
    if (typeof ret == 'undefined'){
        ret = []
    }
    else {
        ret = Links.find().fetch()[0].songs;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And I am using the sortable plugin and more importantly its `update` callback which updates everytime the user changes a position the list or an element is added to the list.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#playlist" ).sortable({
    update: function(){
    Template.list.updateList(); //MODIFIES DB CONTENTS, AND MAIN_LIST's VALUES CHANGE
     }});
    $( "#playlist" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

**The problem: ** If a page already has list elements when it's loaded, for one time only, I would like to add a class that hides (`.addClass("hide")`) each of the `next_song` elements that are on the page at that time. This *will work only until main_list changes* by a call to `Template.list.updateList` above, after which automagically, the added class will disappear - most likely due to the re-rendering that is occuring since the main_list depends on the db changes.

The following in the JQuery snippet I use to try and accomplish this.

```
$("#playlist li .next_song").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("hide_song");
})
```

[Here is a demo. Try plugging in the above JQUery code into the console. and then move the list elements around to see the problem.](http://mixtape.meteor.com/tape/000d9)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just determine whether that will be the case in a helper function?

```
Template.the_playlist.helpers({
    'list_elements_exist': function() {
        return (!!$('#playlist li').length);
    }
}
```

Then you can just insert the logic straight into the template:

```
<div class="next_song{{#if list_elements_exist}} hide_song{{/if}}">...</div>
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that this will float with reactivity depending on the structure of your app.  If it doesn't work properly, I'd introduce a new session boolean, `list_elements`, the value of which is returned by the helper function above.  It should be fairly easy to update its value in event handlers or `created` callbacks to keep it tracking whether there are any items in the list or not, and this will guarantee the list renders as required regardless of other dependencies changing.